# React Native: Invariant violation: View config not found for name path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am pretty new to React Native and I am having a problem importing material ui icon into the code.
Importing material ui icon is successful. However, when I place the material ui icon inside the View tag, it throw an error:

Invariant Violation: View config not found for name path

Here is what I have so far:

```html
import CheckCircle                    from '@material-ui/icons/CheckCircle';


<View>
 <Content padder>
  <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 15, alignSelf: 'center'}}>
    <View style={{borderBottomColor: '#00529b', width: 50, borderBottomWidth: 10}}/>
    <View style={{borderBottomColor: '#00529b', width: 50, borderBottomWidth: 10, marginLeft: 5}}/>
    <View style={{borderBottomColor: '#00529b', width: 50, borderBottomWidth: 10, marginLeft: 5}}/>
    <View style={{borderBottomColor: '#00529b', width: 50, borderBottomWidth: 10, marginLeft: 5}}/>
    <View style={{borderBottomColor: '#00529b', width: 50, borderBottomWidth: 10, marginLeft: 5}}/>
    <CheckCircle />
  </View>
 </Content>
</View>
```

Could anyone please help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Which package are you using?

Comment: @RutulPatel Material-ui/icons

Comment: did you link it ? ` react-native link react-native-vector-icons`